# Map Java class to Morphia 2

Tags: java, mongodb, migration, morphia

I'm trying to migrate this code from Morphia 1.3 to Morphia 2.0

```
Morphia morphia;
List(A.class, B.class, C.class, D.class)
.foldLeft(morphia, (acc, curr) -> morphia.map(curr));
```

which works but it's deprecated,
so I tried this

```
Mapper mapper = datastore.getMapper();
List(A.class, B.class, C.class, D.class)
.foldLeft(mapper, (acc, curr) -> mapper.map(curr));
```

I'm getting

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<MappedClass> to Mapper

How can I migrate this code to Morphia 2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're writing scala (or maybe kotlin) but if I remember that API correctly, the first parameter to `foldLeft` is the accumulator variable in which the results of the operation are folded.  As such, you can fold a `MappedClass` in to a `Mapper`.  You don't need to do anything with those return values (in fact you should ignore them).  Instead, just do a `map` on that list or a `forEach`.  Generally, Morphia users don't need to worry about `MappedClass` references at all.